# inserting forward/back navigation into header of post/portfolio section of wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, import

trying to put a nav menu beside the menu in a theme, but specifically only in one section, the portfolio section. not the homepage. but every time I try to add the code to the header, it gets added to the homepage as well. the code for the nav flips to the previous/next posts in the portfolio - which is built the same structurally as a blog posts. Do I create an alternate header.php and import it into a porfolio-single.php post? Or add it to the header.php and hide it somehow so it only appears in one section?!?? The nav I want was originally in the footer of the portfolio-single.php I do customization but this one is a bit trickier, would appreciate the feedback. here's the code I grabbed from the portfolio-single.php file:

```
<div class="portfolio-meta">
    <nav id="nav-single">
        <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'mega' ); ?></h3>
        <span class="nav-back"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $portfolio_page ); ?>"><i class="icon-remove"></i> <?php _e( 'Back', 'mega' ); ?></a></span>

        <?php if ( get_next_post() ) : ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <span class="nav-previous"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( '<i class="icon-caret-left"></i> Previous', 'mega' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( get_previous_post() ) : ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <span class="nav-next"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next <i class="icon-caret-right"></i>', 'mega' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you like to navigate through single post right? I think this might work and just follow the same rule for the other link if it works, you can clean it up too.

```
<?php 
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
   if( !empty( $prev_post ) ): ?>
   <li class="ico-caret-left">
   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>">
      previous
   </a>
   </li>
<?php
  endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an if-then statement that specifies the navigation should only appear in the header when it is the "Portfolio" category (or page, post, or whatever type "Portfolio" is).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the other answer here as I've been trying to answer for like 25 minutes but SO wouldn't let me. Anyway, the other answer is more complete, so please accept that one.